# What Is The Difference Between 'To Create' And 'To Make'?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

As far as I know **to make** means making something using some material or materials

**To create** means making something out of nothing

Is my impression correct?

Comment: I believe you have the answer already. Just try looking up **[make](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make)** and **[create](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/create)**

Comment: I know but i got confused when I the same question on englishforums and got this answer

Comment: The difference between 'make' and 'create' is not exactly as you have characterized it.

'make' can be used in various ways. For example, it can mean 'cause', as in "Louise made the children laugh". There are also several idioms that use 'make': 'make a mistake', 'make an appointment', 'make sense', etc. 'create' cannot be used in any of those ways.

'make' also means 'create', whether it is from previously existing materials, or from nothing. 'create' can also be used for making something from previously existing materials, but it, too, is used in certain idioms, like 'create an impression'.

Comment: If you are a fairly new learner, I suggest you stick to what the dictionary tells you. You will learn the extended usages and meanings of any word, once you start using it frequently. I believe this is the case with any language.

Comment: But they said create can also be used to make something from previously existing materials. How?

Comment: Please edit your question to specify your specific area of confusion - if possible, with a couple of examples of sentences where you're unsure which verb is most appropriate.  Otherwise I'm voting to close the question as either having insufficient context, being too broad, or being answerable with a dictionary.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To **[make](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make)** is to:

> *to produce something, often using a particular substance or material.*

Eg: *He's making a mixture of salt and water*.

To **[create](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/create)** is to:

> *to make something new, or invent something.*

Eg: *He's creating a complex chemical compound, using salt and water.*

The confusion you would have is "*How can he create a compound from nothing? He surely uses available ingredients.*"

To *'create'* something is to make something new, something that doesn't exist so far. This compound is his creation. If he wanted, say a solution of salt and water, he would, *'make'* it, rather than to *'create'* it, because this compound already exists. But if he's making new solution, something that hasn't been made yet, then he's *'creating'* it.

**Note:** To '*create*' or '*make*' something is independent of what it is made of. Rather, the focus is given to the end product.

Comment: @varun_nair the way you explained helped a lot

Comment: But if create is used for something that has been made yet. Why is it used in this sentence:. Create a stackexchange account,create an amazon account etc. Amazon and stackexchange already exist. No?

Comment: When you are creating an account in Amazon or stackexchange, you are making a new account right? Your account is not there until you make it. That's when you '_create_' an account. These sites may have other accounts, but your account is new.

Comment: You are creating an account, you are not making a new Amazon or Stackexchange site, just an account in it. So you are '_creating_' something new.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-create-and-make   check this link. Why did they say to create means to bring something into existence out of nothing

Comment: That is exactly what it means. That's perfectly in sync with my answer.

Comment: But in your example salt and water already exist. There is no mention out of which were 2 lights made

Comment: Salt and water exists. A solution of salt and water also exists. But in my first example, **the person is making a new compound**, with salt and water, which isn't the normal solution of salt in water, it is something new. **The ingredients may exist, but the compound doesn't exist. That's why it is being '_created_' and not '_made_'**

Comment: But the definition of create is bringing something into existence out of *nothing*

Comment: '_Nothing_' in that context may not mean absolutely nothing. Matter can neither be created nor destroyed, it can only be transferred from one state to another. So something will be used to create another thing.

Comment: It may be possible they are trying to use some special definitions of these words to make a theological point, but that has nothing to do with grammar(in that quora link)

Comment: If you want it to strictly stay in the grammar/ word meaning sense, then I suggest you to close your eyes to Quora and use a dictionary. That's what I explained in the answer. Trust the dictionary.

Comment: I get it what you are trying to say. But in that context. Created could mean made out of nothing. Cz how'd we know out of what did god make the moon and the sun

Comment: That is a whole new topic of discussion - creation of the universe. So let's not venture into that. Use the dictionary meanings. It should help you. Leave out everything else

Comment: @user64158 "create" and "make" are similar words and often have the same meaning. Anytime you can use the one of the words, you can use the other one. However, "create" is usually used "to make something new, or invent something" while "make" is usually used for things that have existed before.  For example, we almost always use "create" for art but when something comes from an assembly line we do not say "create".

Answer (score 0):

With my little box of paints and a simple brush, I created a masterpiece.
In the process I made a mess.

Think of it as a matter of degree. You’re not creating anything from nothing, but you are investing a significant amount of energy or talent. There’s a hint of artistry, design or craftsmanship, rather than just hard work.

I’d never claim to create a cake or a meal, though I can make either.
Few builders would claim to create houses, no matter how much effort they’d put into it. Someone else designed it, they did the heavy lifting.